# How to memoize a function that uses core.async and non-blocking channel read?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

I'd like to use `memoize` for a function that uses `core.async` and `<!` e.g

```
(defn foo [x]
  (go
    (<! (timeout 2000))
    (* 2 x)))
```

(In the real-life, it could be useful in order to cache the results of server calls)

I was able to achieve that by writing a core.async version of memoize (almost the same code as memoize):

```
(defn memoize-async [f]
  (let [mem (atom {})]
    (fn [& args]
      (go
        (if-let [e (find @mem args)]
          (val e)
         (let [ret (<! (apply f args))]; this line differs from memoize [ret (apply f args)]
            (swap! mem assoc args ret)
            ret))))))
```

Example of usage:

```
(def foo-memo (memoize-async foo))
(go (println (<! (foo-memo 3)))); delay because of (<! (timeout 2000))

(go (println (<! (foo-memo 3)))); subsequent calls are memoized => no delay
```

I am wondering if there are simpler ways to achieve the same result.

**Remark: I need a solution that works with `<!`. For `<!!`, see this question: [How to memoize a function that uses core.async and blocking channel read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781858/how-to-memoize-a-function-that-uses-core-async-and) **

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in memoize function for this.  Start by defining a method that reads from a channel and returns the value:

```
 (defn wait-for [ch]
      (<!! ch))
```

Note that we'll use `<!!` and not `<!` because we want this function block until there is data on the channel in all cases.  `<!` only exhibits this behavior when used in a form inside of a go block.

You can then construct your memoized function by composing this function with `foo`, like such:

```
(def foo-memo (memoize (comp wait-for foo)))
```

`foo` returns a channel, so `wait-for` will block until that channel has a value (i.e. until the operation inside `foo` finished).

`foo-memo` can be used similar to your example above, except you do not need the call to `<!` because `wait-for` will block for you:

```
(go (println (foo-memo 3))
```

You can also call this outside of a go block, and it will behave like you expect (i.e. block the calling thread until foo returns).

Comment: It looks like `<!!` is implemented on the `clojure` side by using `take!` with a promise; the `take!` callback triggers the promise, which allows the function to complete.  It looks like there's an open source library for exposing JS promises to `clojurescript`.  You might be able to implement `<!!` using that library.  I'll try and whip something up tonight, if you don't get it before then.

Comment: After trying for the better part of two hours, I don't think I can do better than your original solution. The problem I keep running into is that `<!` must be called directly from within a go block (not in a function called from a go block), which limits your ability to define a memo'd function that returns the value you want to hold (i.e. you don't want your memo to hold channels).  The promise libraries I mentioned earlier work with callbacks and events, which are not useful for this situation.  My solution works in `clojure`, but I can't see a way to make it work in `cljs`.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your efforts. Do you think I could suggest to the `core.aync` team to add `memoize-async`?

Comment: Done, thanks.  You can definitely suggest that method to core.async.  I'm not sure what the process is, or whether they'll accept it, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: A disadvantage of using something like `memoize-async` as written, is that the longer-running the asynchronous operation, the higher the chance of redundant fetches - nothing is being stored to indicate that a resolution is in-flight for a particular value.  There was talk a while back of [promise-chan](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/ASYNC-103) - you could memoize something like that naively and have the right thing happen.  You can also get crazy with the state management and channel multiplexing, if you don't want to go the promise-chan route.

Answer (score 0):

This was a little trickier than I expected. Your solution isn't correct, because when you call your memoized function again with the same arguments, sooner than the first run finishes running its go block, you will trigger it again and get a miss. This is often the case when you process lists with core.async.

The one below uses core.async's pub/sub to solve this (tested in CLJS only):

```
(def lookup-sentinel  #?(:clj ::not-found :cljs (js-obj))
(def pending-sentinel #?(:clj ::pending   :cljs (js-obj))

(defn memoize-async
  [f]
  (let [>in (chan)
        pending (pub >in :args)
        mem (atom {})]
    (letfn
        [(memoized [& args]
           (go
             (let [v (get @mem args lookup-sentinel)]
               (condp identical? v
                 lookup-sentinel
                 (do
                   (swap! mem assoc args pending-sentinel)
                   (go
                     (let [ret (<! (apply f args))]
                       (swap! mem assoc args ret)
                       (put! >in {:args args :ret ret})))
                   (<! (apply memoized args)))
                 pending-sentinel
                 (let [<out (chan 1)]
                   (sub pending args <out)
                   (:ret (<! <out)))
                 v))))]
        memoized)))
```

NOTE: it probably leaks memory, subscriptions and `<out` channels are not closed

Answer (score 0):

I have used this function in one of my projects to cache HTTP calls. The function caches results for a given amount of time and uses a barrier to prevent executing the function multiple times when the cache is "cold" (due to the context switch inside the go block).

```clj
(defn memoize-af-until
  [af ms clock]
  (let [barrier (async/chan 1)
        last-return (volatile! nil)
        last-return-ms (volatile! nil)]
    (fn [& args]
      (async/go
        (>! barrier :token)
        (let [now-ms (.now clock)]
          (when (or (not @last-return-ms) (< @last-return-ms (- now-ms ms)))
            (vreset! last-return (<! (apply af args)))
            (vreset! last-return-ms now-ms))
          (<! barrier)
          @last-return)))))
```

You can test that it works properly by setting the cache time to 0 and observe that the two function calls take approximately 10 seconds. Without the barrier the two calls would finish at the same time:

```clj
(def memo (memoize-af-until #(async/timeout 5000) 0 js/Date))
(async/take! (memo) #(println "[:a] Finished"))
(async/take! (memo) #(println "[:b] Finished"))
```