# How to memoize a function that uses core.async and blocking channel read?

Tags: clojure, core.async

I'd like to use `memoize` for a function that uses `core.async` and `<!!` e.g

```
(defn foo [x]
  (go
    (<!! (timeout 2000))
    (* 2 x)))
```

(In the real-life, it could be useful in order to cache the results of server calls)

I was able to achieve that by writing a core.async version of memoize (almost the same code as memoize):

```
(defn memoize-async [f]
  (let [mem (atom {})]
    (fn [& args]
      (go
        (if-let [e (find @mem args)]
          (val e)
         (let [ret (<! (apply f args))]; this line differs from memoize [ret (apply f args)]
            (swap! mem assoc args ret)
            ret))))))
```

Example of usage:

```
(def foo-memo (memoize-async foo))
(go (println (<!! (foo-memo 3)))); delay because of (<!! (timeout 2000))

(go (println (<!! (foo-memo 3)))); subsequent calls are memoized => no delay
```

I am wondering if there are simpler ways to achieve the same result.

**Remark: I need a solution that works with `<!!`. For `<!`, see this question: [How to memoize a function that uses core.async and non-blocking channel read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698536/how-to-memoize-a-function-that-uses-core-async-and)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built in memoize function for this.  Start by defining a method that reads from a channel and returns the value:

```
 (defn wait-for [ch]
      (<!! ch))
```

Note that we'll use `<!!` and not `<!` because we want this function block until there is data on the channel in all cases.  `<!` only exhibits this behavior when used in a form inside of a go block.

You can then construct your memoized function by composing this function with `foo`, like such:

```
(def foo-memo (memoize (comp wait-for foo)))
```

`foo` returns a channel, so `wait-for` will block until that channel has a value (i.e. until the operation inside `foo` finished).

`foo-memo` can be used similar to your example above, except you do not need the call to `<!!` because `wait-for` will block for you:

```
(go (println (foo-memo 3))
```

You can also call this outside of a go block, and it will behave like you expect (i.e. block the calling thread until foo returns).